# How to configure Apache to rewrite following condition?

Tags: mod-rewrite, apache2

I'd like to enable Apache `mod_rewrite` to work as follow:

```
www.mysite.example/g/abcde   "redirect" to www.mysite.example/mypage.php?code=abcde&mode=g
```

and

```
www.mysite.example/v/abcde   "redirect" to www.mysite.example/mypage.php?code=abcde&mode=v
```

My questions are:

1. How to configure mod_rewrite in my Ubuntu 18.04 installation ?
2. How to write that configurations ?

Answer (score 0):

I solved:

```
RewriteRule ^g/([A-Za-z0-9-/_]+)?$ /g.php?param1=$1&%{QUERY_STRI$
```